# Run time of recursive algorithm in terms of big O

Tags: algorithm

what will be the run time of the following recursive algorithm in terms of big O [Assuming f1(n) = O(log n)]

```
function Recurse(A[1..n])
        f1(n)
        m <-- n/3
        t1 <-- Recurse(A[1..m])
        t2 <-- Recurse(A[(m+1)..2m])
        t3 <-- Recurse(A[(2m+1)..3m])
        return (t1+t2+t3)/3
end function
```

will it be O(log n)? If not, then what is the accurate result?

Answer (score 0):

By using master theorem

T(n) = aT(n/b) + f(n)  where a >= 1 b > 1

n is the size of the problem.
a is the number of subproblems in the recursion.
n/b is the size of each subproblem. (Here it is assumed that all subproblems are essentially the same size.)
f (n) is the cost of the work done outside the recursive calls, which includes the cost of dividing the problem and the cost of merging the solutions to the subproblems.

T(n)=log n *(3*n/3)
T(n)=nLog(n)

```
http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Master_theorem
```